# Bug in collision detecting algorithm, Javascript

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

OK so I'm making a 2D platform game in JavaScript and for my collision detecting I have 2 types of objects:
game objects which are detected by focus areas
and focus areas; which detect the objects
both have 4 coordinates which form a box x1 and y1 are the left/top and x2 and y2 are the left/bottom

the game object's box coordinates are unchanging numbers which must be calculated to be relative to the game objects position whereas the focus areas coordinates are updated to be the exact spots

my problem is for some reason when this code (below) comes across a focus area that is smaller than the game object (in coordinates) it goes undetected unless the focus area conflicts with the upper-left pixel of the game object's box, how do I fix this? (by the way this is all in a double 'for loop')

```
            var O_x=game.objects[ii].phy.pos.x,
                O_aur_x_1=game.objects[ii].col.aur.x1,
                O_aur_x_2=game.objects[ii].col.aur.x2,

                F_x_1=game.focusAreas[i].x1,
                F_x_2=game.focusAreas[i].x2,

                O_y=game.objects[ii].phy.pos.y,
                O_aur_y_1=game.objects[ii].col.aur.y1,
                O_aur_y_2=game.objects[ii].col.aur.y2,

                F_y_1=game.focusAreas[i].y1,
                F_y_2=game.focusAreas[i].y2;


        if      ( (O_x + O_aur_x_1) >= F_x_1 && (O_x + O_aur_x_1) <= F_x_2 || F_x_1 >= (O_x + O_aur_x_1) && F_x_1 <=(O_x + O_aur_x_2))
        {// if object's x1 is within xfocus range
        }
        else if ( (O_x + O_aur_x_2) >= F_x_1 && (O_x + O_aur_x_2)<= F_x_2  || F_x_2 >= (O_x + O_aur_x_1) && F_x_1 <=(O_x + O_aur_x_2))
        {// if object's x2 is within xfocus range
        }
        else{continue;}

        if      ( (O_y + O_aur_y_1) >= F_y_1 && (O_y + O_aur_y_1) <= F_y_2 || F_y_1 >= (O_y + O_aur_y_1) && F_y_1 <=(O_y + O_aur_y_2))
        {// if object's y1 is within yfocus range
        }
        else if ( (O_y + O_aur_y_2) >= F_y_1 && (O_y + O_aur_y_2) <= F_y_2 || F_y_2 >= (O_y + O_aur_y_1) && F_y_1 <=(O_y + O_aur_y_2))
        {// if object's y2 is within yfocus range
        }
        else{continue;}
```

Comment: im guessing you need more than 4 coordinates to make a real "border" for your squares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mind your parentheses!

JS uses C-style short-circuit evaluation, meaning:

- if "a && b" then b is only evaluated, if a is true, the evaluation is
  exited as false as soon as any expression is false.
- if "a || b" then b is only evaluated if a is false, the evaluation is
  exited as true as soon as any expression is true.

So you need an extra pair of brackets to group the expressions on both sides of the or-operator:

```
if ((ax1 >= bx1 && ax1 <= bx2) || (bx1 >= ax1 && bx1 <= ax2)) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: was'nt the exact solution, but even better: you probally saved me many hours and possibly giving up the project thanks!

Comment: You could also say that "&&" is binding deeper than "||" does. But this "short-circuit" evaluation is also, why things like `"var a = thisProperty || thatProperty;"` work. You can even do things like just saying `"doThis() && doThat();"` for `"if (doThis()) doThat();"`.

Comment: Yet another hint: You're calculating values like `O_x + O_aur_x_1`multiple times, you could assign these to a local variable. Also, you could probably assign `F_x_1`and so on in the outer loop. Given that you're doing i*ii iterations, this could save some runtime.